# PHP Protecting $_GET

Tags: php, mysql

I don't know why this isn't working. If **?Session=2** is not from you, then you will go back to your account.

This is my code:

```
<?php
$hosts = $mysql->query("SELECT * FROM user_host WHERE uid = '" . $_SESSION['id'] . "'");
$hostsFetch = $hosts->fetch_assoc();

$userq = $mysql->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '" . $_SESSION['id'] . "'");
$userf = $userq->fetch_assoc();

if (isset($_GET['session'])) {
    $_SESSION['siteid'] = $mysql->real_escape_string($_GET['session']);
    header('Location: ./home');
}

if (trim($_SESSION['siteid']) == '') {
    $_SESSION['siteid'] = $userf['default'];
}

$hosts2 = $mysql->query("SELECT * FROM user_host WHERE id = '" . $hostsFetch['id'] . "'");
$hosts2Fetch = $hosts2->fetch_assoc();
```

This is the problem / Its not working

I still can go to **?session=2** but it isn't mine

```
if ($hosts2Fetch['uid'] != $_SESSION['id']) {
    $_SESSION['siteid'] = $userf['default'];
}


$host = $mysql->query("SELECT * FROM user_host WHERE uid = '" . $_SESSION['id'] . "'");
while ($item = $host->fetch_assoc()) {
    ?>
    <option
        value="./home?session=<?php echo $item['id']; ?>" <?php echo($_SESSION['siteid'] == $item['id'] ? 'selected' : '') ?>><?php echo $item['name'] . ' - ' . $item['domein']; ?></option>
<?php

}
?>
```

Thank You.

Comment: `session_start();`?

Comment: There is a session start, this is a small piece of code from my page

Comment: You guys always leave that out.

Comment: Yeah, every single time. But it's kind of magic how you just forget the `session_start()` line but manage to include everything else, including the `<?php` part.

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that everything in PHP is case sensitive. You use the querystring `Session`, but in code you can't refer to `session`, you must use `Session`.

You mention `?Session=2` is used, but in code you refer to `$_GET['session']`. The case of these two should match.

Comment: and what do you mean by that Mr47

Comment: no, not everything is case sensitive. array keys and variable names are, but function names AREN'T. `$foo = 7; $fOO = 8` are different variables, but `foo()` and `FoO()` are the same function.

Comment: @Mr47 go trhough the code `value="./home?session=<?php echo` session is lowercase. if thats even relevant

Comment: @Mr47: the wonderous joys of PHP, where consistency is anathema

Comment: @meda Perhaps this comes in from another page and the case does not match there, but you are probably correct. If the correct answer shows up, I'll delete mine.